# Using ltree query in plpgsql function as param in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, ltree

I want to execute query with ltree param in plpgsql function... but i can`t understand how to use quotes in this functions...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_select(BIGINT) RETURNS setof categories AS 
$$
DECLARE
    s_cat ALIAS FOR $1;

    queryText TEXT;
    result categories%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN
    queryText := 'SELECT * FROM categories WHERE cat_tree ~ \'*.\'|| s_cat::text ||\'.*\'';

    FOR result IN EXECUTE queryText
    LOOP
        RETURN NEXT result;
    END LOOP;

    RETURN;

END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

How to do this ???

After executing this code in psql I get error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "."
LINE 10: ... := 'SELECT * FROM categories WHERE cat_tree ~ \'*.\'|| s_ca...
```

Final working verison:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_select(BIGINT) RETURNS setof categories AS 
$$
DECLARE
    s_cat ALIAS FOR $1;

    queryText TEXT;
    result categories%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN

    queryText := 'SELECT * FROM categories WHERE cat_tree ~ ''' || ('*.'|| s_cat::text || '.*')::lquery || '''';

    FOR result IN EXECUTE queryText
    LOOP
        RETURN NEXT result;
    END LOOP;

    RETURN;

END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Thanks, but it don`t help me, I try out it before you comment buuut...

Comment: Ok, can you provide table structure and some example data for example as sql fiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/)?

Comment: The way to quote a single quote is to prepend another single quote. Don't bother with backslashes, they're deprecated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be misusing the backslash, but anyway putting this query into a text variable shouldn't be needed in the first place.

What about this form:

```
FOR result IN SELECT * FROM categories WHERE cat_tree ~ '*.'|| s_cat::text || '.*'
LOOP
    RETURN NEXT result;
END LOOP;
```

And if the LOOP just has to return the results, you may just as well avoid it and  return the query directly:

```
 RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM categories WHERE cat_tree ~ '*.'|| s_cat::text || '.*';
```

**EDIT:**
Since the operator is `ltree ~ lquery` and `~` binds tighter than `||`, the right operand should be parenthesized and cast to `lquery`:

```
 RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM categories
   WHERE cat_tree ~ ('*.'|| s_cat::text || '.*')::lquery;
```

Comment: Thanks for answer... but your version don`t work for the same reason. Need for quoting single quotes. imho

Comment: @dezconnect: no it's a different reason. I've edited the query in the edit.

Comment: And I need LOOP beacause it 'testing' code, in real function must do more =)